# running dotnet test on NUnit project generates cs1061 on referenced WPF project

Tags: c#, unit-testing, msbuild

I need to run this in an automated AWS environment, so I need to do everything via command line. As it stands, the unit tests will run fine so long as I run them in Visual Studio, but when I try running via "dotnet test" I get the following error on the WPF project that is indirectly referenced.

Here is a sample log of the errors (I removed specifics)

`\MainWindow.xaml.cs(29,13): error CS0103: The name 'InitializeComponent' does not exist in the current context [\MyProject\MyControl.csproj] \MainWindow.xaml.cs(43,18): error CS1061: 'MainWindow' does not contain a definition for 'MyPanel' and no accessible extension method 'MyPanel' accepting a first argument of type 'MainWindow' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?) [\MyProject\MyControl.csproj]`

I ran: dotnet test -t from the project.  I was expecting a list of the tests, and got the error message instead.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: Without Code, hard to say anything directed to the problem. From experience, typical reasons are mismatch of frameworks in the environments or a mismatch of the namespace/class names between XAML and code-behind file - (it works on the dev environment because of temporary and intermediate files still in there). For better feedback please share some code